# Blazor, LINQ ORDER BY of String with Quarter and Year

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a Blazor Server .Net 6 app and I would like to use LINQ to parse a string that contains Quarter - Year (count) that will be used in a dropdown list.  But I would like to order the list with the newsest first.  As it’s a string I cant use the normal Order By in LINQ

```
Example data:
Q4 – 2022 (7)
Q3 – 2022 (9)
Q2 – 2022 (10)
Q1 – 2022 (15)
Q4 – 2021 (18)
Q3 – 2021 (5)
Q2 – 2021 (4)
Q1 – 2021 (1)
```

Any thoughts how I can order this string so the data will always appear in the above order

TIA

Comment: The input data is coming from a list that my app is getting from a Service 

The list has a Column called QuarterAndYear which is a string.  Im doing a GROUP BY on this list to get DISTINCT list of distinct values but I cant get it to order correctley

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` along with `Range` as long as your data is consistent in format.

```
var data = new string[] {
    "Q4 – 2022 (7)",
    "Q3 – 2022 (9)",
    "Q2 – 2022 (10)",
    "Q1 – 2022 (15)",
    "Q4 – 2021 (18)",
    "Q3 – 2021 (5)",
    "Q2 – 2021 (4)",
    "Q1 – 2021 (1)"};

var orderedData = data.OrderBy(d=> d[5..9]).ThenBy(d => d[1..2]);
```

This orders by the characters at positions 6 to 9 (the year) and then orders by the characters at 1 to 2 (the quarter).
*It is crucial that the data always matches that pattern for this to work.*

[Try it out](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoIgBgAIiyA6AGQEs8BHAbmuoBuAQyj0AJkIxD6AXnp4YAd0ZlaAbQC69AN7V6++gCIAiinqBkAnolaJEvQAUAdgCUhtHoMmAzBas279gCcru5UBkbGdpbWtg6qIR76JmS+MQFkAKwJYZ6mqTYp9mQAHNnh3vnkDlluiRFRflX2KGW5KdEFca4AvnxU1ABm0DBCYAAW9sKi7BgwALb0nOKSQswA8lBiMFAAQgCe9mIyAHziakjMzIEazswAKmMwePuHsqdiaizMJDfOdUyBewzebOHhAA=)